# Slow transfer speeds for the last chunk of data transferred from Python ASGI app

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, asgi, hypercorn

While attempting to analyse the network transfer speeds using a hypercorn ASGI app and requests API, there is a significant drop in speed for the last chunk.

**Hypercorn ASGI app**

```py
from typing import Any

ONE_KB = 1024
ONE_MB = ONE_KB * ONE_KB
ONE_GB = ONE_MB * ONE_KB

chunk_size = 256 * ONE_KB

dump = bytes(ONE_GB)  # 1GB


async def app(scope: Any, receive: Any, send: Any) -> None:
    '''
    Run: `hypercorn app:app --bind localhost:7001`
    '''
    assert scope["type"] == "http"

    await send(
        {
            "type": "http.response.start",
            "status": 200,
            "headers": [[b"Content-Type", b"application/octet-stream"], [b"Content-Length", str(len(dump)).encode()]],
        }
    )

    chunks = len(dump) // chunk_size

    for i in range(chunks):
        await send(
            {
                "type": "http.response.body",
                "body": dump[i * chunk_size : (i + 1) * chunk_size],
                "more_body": i != chunks - 1,
            }
        )
```

**test.py**

```py
import time
import requests

ONE_MB = 2**20

data_size_mb = 1000


async def test_speed():
    # Parse the URL to get host and path
    path = "/"

    start_time = time.time()

    # Create a TCP socket
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        # Connect to the server
        s.connect((host, port))

        # Send HTTP GET request
        request = f"GET {path} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {host}\r\n\r\n"
        s.sendall(request.encode())

        # Create a BufferedReader from the socket
        bufferedReader = io.BufferedReader(s.makefile("rb"))

        try:
            # Read response headers
            headers = bufferedReader.readline()
            while headers.strip():
                headers = bufferedReader.readline()
            bufferedReader.flush()

            # Receive response in chunks and write to file
            recv_size = 0
            unit = 8
            chunks = []
            for i in range(unit):
                st = time.time()
                for _ in range(20 * 1000):
                    data = bufferedReader.read(ONE_MB // unit)
                    recv_size += len(data)
                    # chunks.append(data)

                chunk_time = time.time() - st
                spd = data_size_mb // (unit * chunk_time)
                print("Chunk #{}: Time {:.6f} seconds, Speed {:.2f}".format(i + 1, chunk_time, spd))
        finally:
            bufferedReader.close()

    recv_data_mb = recv_size / ONE_MB
    print("[*] Received data ", recv_size / ONE_MB, "MB")
    print("[*] Chunks size {}".format(str(len(chunks))))

    end_time = time.time()

    recv_time = end_time - start_time
    recv_speed = recv_data_mb / recv_time

    print("===========================================")
    print("Data size: {:.2f} MB".format(data_size_mb))
    print("Recv data size: {:.2f} MB".format(recv_data_mb))
    print("Recv time: {:.6f} seconds".format(recv_time))
    print("Recv speed: {:.2f} mbps".format(recv_speed))
    print("===========================================")
```

**Output:**

```bash
$ python test.py
Chunk #1: Time 0.943959 seconds, Speed 2648.00
Chunk #2: Time 0.998727 seconds, Speed 2503.00
Chunk #3: Time 0.937339 seconds, Speed 2667.00
Chunk #4: Time 0.947274 seconds, Speed 2639.00
Chunk #5: Time 0.941455 seconds, Speed 2655.00
Chunk #6: Time 0.951273 seconds, Speed 2628.00
Chunk #7: Time 0.980101 seconds, Speed 2550.00
Chunk #8: Time 5.945689 seconds, Speed 420.00
[*] Received data  20000.0 MB
[*] Chunks size 0
===========================================
Data size: 20000.00 MB
Recv data size: 20000.00 MB
Recv time: 14.233940 seconds
Recv speed: 1405.09 mbps
===========================================
```

**Expectation:**
The transfer speed must be identical for all the chunks.

**Actual:**
The transfer speed for the last chunk is significantly slower.

**Env**

- The machine has over 1 TB of RAM and sufficient CPU.
- Python version: `3.10.12`

Comment: I would suggest that this comes from a 5 seconds timeout in the server before it closes the connection since it is awaiting another request on the same connection. Try not to announce that you support persistent connections by announcing only HTTP/1.0 as protocol version and not HTTP/1.1 (which implicitly announces support for persistent connections).